# How to keep accessibility service enabled after re-installing the app from Android Studio?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

In my app I have to enable accessibility for my app each time I run the app, but I have to run the app many times and it is time consuming, enabling the service each time.

Is there a way that the accessibility settings stay enabled after each install from android studio?

Comment: Have you found solution please?

Comment: No there is no solution, at least not that I know of.

Comment: I think there a way on android studio to run an ADB command after installing the app its should right a way grant access agen